# Why animation restarts on tick of the chronometer?

Tags: android, animation, chronometer

I have a class with a view for animation and a chronometer. This is the content of my onCreate method:

```
    chronometer = ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.clock_time));
    chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(this);

    chronometer.start();

    v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    final SurfaceView surfaceViewTimer = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view_timer);

    final RelativeLayout timeView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
    ViewTreeObserver observer = timeView.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int animationDuration = getIntent().getIntExtra(
                    MainActivity.TOTAL_TIME, -1);
            TranslateAnimation surfaceGrowingAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
                    0, 0, timeView.getHeight(), 0);

            surfaceGrowingAnimation.setDuration(animationDuration * 1000);          

            surfaceViewTimer.startAnimation(surfaceGrowingAnimation);
```

I have this other method to the chronometer:

```
@Override
public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {

    int intervalOfVibration = getIntent().getIntExtra(
            MainActivity.VIBRATION_INTERVAL, -1);

    long elapsedMillis = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.clock_time))
            .getBase()) / 1000;

    if (((elapsedMillis % intervalOfVibration) == 0) && (elapsedMillis > 0))
        v.vibrate(300);

}
```

But my animation restarts on each tick of the chronometer.

How can I fix this?

Now I get these errors:

```
11-26 17:58:57.908: W/dalvikvm(15596): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aaca228)
11-26 17:58:57.908: E/AndroidRuntime(15596): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-26 17:58:57.908: E/AndroidRuntime(15596): java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver() again
11-26 17:58:57.908: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.checkIsAlive(ViewTreeObserver.java:492)
11-26 17:58:57.908: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.java:339)
11-26 17:58:57.908: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at com.activities.TimerActivity$1.onGlobalLayout(TimerActivity.java:64)
11-26 17:58:57.908: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:549)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OnGlobalLayoutListener` is being called every time the screen is laid out, which includes each time the `Chronometer` changes (since it changes width, possibly height, etc., and everything invalidates).

Use [`removeOnGlobalLayoutListener();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeOnGlobalLayoutListener%28android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener%29) in your `onGlobalLayout()` method:

```
ViewTreeObserver observer = timeView.getViewTreeObserver(); // Make this final
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Your code ...

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) // Use old, deprecated method
            timeView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        else // Use new method
            timeView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
}
```

**Note**: You will have to use [`removeGlobalOnLayoutListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeGlobalOnLayoutListener%28android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener%29) instead, for APIs < 16. *(The method name was changed in API level 16. They perform in an identical manner.)*

Comment: Thank you, but here apeears this message in my Eclipse: The method removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){}) is undefined for the type new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){}

Comment: I've got this error in my logcat: unable to resolve virtual method removeOnGlobalLayoutListener. Some idea to fix it?

Comment: What device/API level are you running on?

Comment: My app is from API level 7, and I'm running on a device with 2.1-update 1 version

Comment: Ah, yes. As my note says, for APIs under 16, you need to use `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener()` (notice **removeGlobalOn**, not **removeOnGlobal**). I have edited the code in my post to reflect this.

Comment: @user1771682 Sorry, obviously not on my game today. Updated the solution again. (The issue was that keeping the `final ViewTreeObserver` is not allowed; it expires before `onGlobalLayout()` is called.)